# This referenced script (x) on this Behaviour is missing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to create a top dawn game

Here are the errors:

> - The referenced script (PlayerController) on this Behaviour is missing!
> - This referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Player') is missing!
> - This referenced script (unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!
> - This referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Objec 'sample_ground') is missing!

here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class Character2DTopDown : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float acceleration = 100;

    private Vector3 direction;
    private Rigidbody2D body;

    void Start () 
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        body.freezeRotation = true;
        body.gravityScale = 0;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        body.AddForce(direction * body.mass * speed * acceleration);
        
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > speed)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * speed, body.velocity.y);
        }
        
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.y) > speed)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.y) * speed);
        }
    }

    void LookAtCursor()
    {
        Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
        float angle  = Mathf.Atan2(lookPos.y, lookPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        direction = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        LookAtCursor();
    }
}
```

I tried to make my character start walking, but he just stood still

Comment: Welcome to [so] please read the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Are you certain those errors are about the script you've shown? Doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: It's almost exactly as it says - the script is missing (or it can't be compiled). Click on the console message and it will highlight the affected object. You then need to find or fix the script.

Comment: You just mentioned 4 different errors. None of them seem to be caused by the only script you're showing. Please check the console tab again and click on them individually and copy-paste them here, at least the first line of the stack, so we can see what script are causing them. and which line. Grab those mentioned scripts and paste them here as well.

Comment: Make sure all monobehaviour scripts' files have exactly the same name as the class inside them, and only have one monobehaviour class per file